# How to read a txt file and sum the cells within specific rows and columns?

Tags: r, sum, text-files

I have a large txt file.  As listed in the txt listed at the end of this question.  There are three columns, and 677 rows

How to read in the txt below to R, and sum all the numbers in the cells in the row 1-2 and column 300-400.

```
  1.00   0.90   0.76   0.61   0.52   0.36   0.33   0.28   0.18   0.21   0.17   0.12   0.08   0.08   0.00  -0.05  -0.11  -0.09  -0.07  -0.12  -0.15  -0.19  -0.16  -0.05   0.07   0.18   0.26   0.25   0.31   0.36   0.40   0.41   0.53   0.59   0.66   0.72  -0.16  -0.19  -0.20  -0.18  -0.19  -0.22  -0.25  -0.20  -0.22  -0.23  -0.27  -0.29  -0.27  -0.28  -0.30  -0.29  -0.28  -0.28  -0.32  -0.32  -0.35  -0.36  -0.32  -0.27  -0.26  -0.23  -0.20  -0.19  -0.21  -0.16  -0.06   0.00   0.05   0.08   0.15   0.15   0.18   0.24   0.24   0.26   0.22   0.23   0.11   0.06   0.01  -0.01  -0.04  -0.06  -0.16  -0.20  -0.27  -0.26  -0.28  -0.29  -0.30  -0.26  -0.20  -0.24  -0.22  -0.16  -0.14  -0.15  -0.12  -0.07  -0.07  -0.06  -0.03  -0.02   0.02   0.03   0.09   0.01  -0.07  -0.02  -0.16  -0.10  -0.07  -0.01  -0.00   0.01  -0.07  -0.14  -0.00  -0.05  -0.03   0.01   0.06   0.08   0.13   0.10   0.05  -0.06  -0.07  -0.05  -0.03  -0.08  -0.17  -0.07   0.08   0.14   0.10   0.15   0.22   0.19   0.17   0.12   0.08   0.13   0.12   0.08   0.05  -0.07  -0.07  -0.09  -0.11  -0.14  -0.11  -0.13  -0.12  -0.13  -0.18  -0.14  -0.11  -0.02  -0.02   0.00  -0.10  -0.15  -0.25  -0.23  -0.20  -0.22  -0.20  -0.20  -0.22  -0.18  -0.13  -0.09  -0.04  -0.02   0.02   0.02   0.04   0.02   0.04   0.09   0.04  -0.03  -0.11  -0.14  -0.09  -0.07  -0.03  -0.07  -0.09  -0.15  -0.20  -0.27  -0.28  -0.28  -0.25  -0.28  -0.24  -0.14  -0.05   0.05   0.15   0.19   0.18   0.28   0.20   0.38   0.36   0.33   0.32   0.25   0.12  -0.00  -0.09  -0.10  -0.13  -0.06  -0.07  -0.01  -0.12  -0.17  -0.14  -0.07  -0.03   0.07   0.14  -0.00  -0.06  -0.12  -0.18  -0.22  -0.27  -0.25  -0.26  -0.23  -0.18  -0.19  -0.13  -0.15  -0.14  -0.08  -0.07  -0.19  -0.23  -0.29  -0.28  -0.28  -0.27  -0.26  -0.30  -0.27  -0.26  -0.20  -0.18  -0.18  -0.20  -0.20  -0.23  -0.24  -0.23  -0.20  -0.22  -0.25  -0.29  -0.29  -0.28  -0.31  -0.26  -0.22  -0.21  -0.22  -0.23  -0.20  -0.17  -0.16  -0.12  -0.09  -0.06  -0.07  -0.07  -0.05  -0.03  -0.04  -0.06  -0.09  -0.07  -0.12  -0.18  -0.16  -0.16  -0.17  -0.15  -0.14   0.00   0.04  -0.03  -0.08  -0.06  -0.08  -0.10  -0.08  -0.13  -0.13  -0.15  -0.14  -0.07  -0.08  -0.06  -0.03   0.01   0.05   0.07   0.10   0.07   0.03  -0.00  -0.02  -0.04   0.03   0.03  -0.05  -0.03  -0.01  -0.05  -0.07  -0.08  -0.09  -0.08  -0.07  -0.05  -0.07  -0.05  -0.08   0.08   0.12   0.14  -0.02  -0.13   0.01   0.04  -0.10  -0.16  -0.26  -0.27  -0.25  -0.25  -0.26  -0.29  -0.29  -0.34  -0.34  -0.34  -0.29  -0.32  -0.29  -0.27  -0.18  -0.20  -0.17  -0.15  -0.21  -0.25  -0.22  -0.19  -0.23  -0.22  -0.22  -0.16  -0.14  -0.06   0.02   0.05   0.15   0.20   0.23   0.30   0.32   0.25   0.23   0.17   0.14   0.09   0.08  -0.03  -0.02  -0.14  -0.20  -0.19  -0.16  -0.12  -0.10  -0.17  -0.19  -0.18  -0.16  -0.14  -0.08  -0.12  -0.11  -0.06  -0.08   0.00   0.08   0.03   0.08  -0.01   0.01  -0.06  -0.14  -0.06  -0.06  -0.01   0.10   0.09   0.13   0.12   0.09   0.10   0.06   0.07   0.02  -0.00   0.02   0.04   0.08   0.08   0.11   0.10   0.06   0.04   0.01   0.01  -0.02  -0.05  -0.07  -0.11  -0.14  -0.23  -0.28  -0.29  -0.26  -0.14  -0.20  -0.20  -0.27  -0.29  -0.30  -0.16  -0.07  -0.03  -0.05  -0.06  -0.03  -0.01   0.02   0.06   0.10   0.06   0.08   0.11   0.02   0.20   0.22   0.21   0.21   0.20   0.17   0.20   0.19   0.22   0.25   0.29   0.31   0.29   0.31   0.34   0.35   0.29   0.34   0.37   0.37   0.38   0.37   0.37   0.36   0.36   0.37   0.35   0.34   0.34   0.33   0.32   0.30   0.27   0.27   0.18   0.19   0.17   0.18   0.14   0.12   0.12   0.20   0.23   0.29   0.30   0.27   0.30   0.35   0.33   0.30   0.34   0.37   0.37   0.38   0.38   0.36   0.34   0.36   0.34   0.28   0.27   0.28   0.25   0.20   0.22   0.23   0.18   0.20   0.14   0.14   0.10   0.11   0.05   0.02   0.03   0.09   0.15   0.23   0.21   0.13   0.21   0.27   0.16   0.17   0.26   0.24   0.31   0.27   0.28   0.33   0.26   0.26   0.31   0.27   0.24   0.28   0.27   0.22   0.17   0.08   0.02  -0.06   0.01  -0.01  -0.00  -0.03  -0.09  -0.09  -0.07  -0.01   0.07  -0.02  -0.09  -0.04  -0.01  -0.13  -0.16  -0.05  -0.11   0.01  -0.03   0.07   0.09  -0.02   0.01   0.11   0.07  -0.01   0.06   0.11   0.02  -0.02  -0.13  -0.20  -0.22  -0.17  -0.17  -0.15  -0.15  -0.20  -0.21  -0.22  -0.21  -0.19  -0.23  -0.25  -0.24  -0.24  -0.26  -0.26  -0.25  -0.24  -0.21  -0.22  -0.17  -0.16  -0.21  -0.18  -0.13  -0.17  -0.19  -0.14  -0.11  -0.16  -0.19  -0.21  -0.24  -0.25  -0.24  -0.26  -0.25  -0.25  -0.28  -0.28  -0.29  -0.29  -0.28  -0.29  -0.30  -0.29  -0.30  -0.30  -0.30  -0.28  -0.27  -0.27  -0.26  -0.23  -0.26  -0.28  -0.26  -0.26  -0.27  -0.26  -0.23  -0.22  -0.20  -0.21  -0.05   0.25   0.25   0.24   0.21   0.21   0.26   0.20   0.15   0.12   0.10   0.07  -0.01  -0.04  -0.06  -0.09  -0.09 
  0.90   1.00   0.92   0.77   0.63   0.39   0.36   0.28   0.16   0.19   0.20   0.16   0.13   0.11   0.03  -0.04  -0.11  -0.08  -0.06  -0.10  -0.11  -0.16  -0.12  -0.01   0.15   0.26   0.31   0.31   0.33   0.35   0.35   0.35   0.52   0.61   0.72   0.76  -0.19  -0.22  -0.25  -0.18  -0.17  -0.19  -0.21  -0.17  -0.19  -0.21  -0.23  -0.24  -0.22  -0.24  -0.26  -0.25  -0.23  -0.22  -0.28  -0.27  -0.30  -0.32  -0.28  -0.24  -0.24  -0.20  -0.19  -0.17  -0.19  -0.14  -0.02   0.05   0.11   0.13   0.23   0.24   0.28   0.34   0.33   0.35   0.28   0.27   0.15   0.06  -0.00  -0.01  -0.02  -0.05  -0.14  -0.18  -0.25  -0.24  -0.25  -0.26  -0.28  -0.25  -0.20  -0.23  -0.22  -0.18  -0.14  -0.14  -0.11  -0.08  -0.07  -0.05  -0.03  -0.02   0.02   0.03   0.08   0.02  -0.04  -0.01  -0.11  -0.06  -0.04   0.03   0.04   0.06  -0.01  -0.11   0.07   0.01   0.02   0.08   0.10   0.13   0.18   0.14   0.06  -0.03  -0.01  -0.03  -0.00  -0.07  -0.15  -0.07   0.06   0.11   0.12   0.18   0.27   0.26   0.25   0.21   0.17   0.22   0.22   0.16   0.09  -0.03  -0.03  -0.05  -0.06  -0.10  -0.05  -0.07  -0.07  -0.08  -0.13  -0.08  -0.07   0.02   0.03   0.06  -0.02  -0.06  -0.20  -0.18  -0.14  -0.16  -0.15  -0.16  -0.19  -0.15  -0.09  -0.05  -0.00   0.02   0.07   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.03   0.08   0.02  -0.04  -0.12  -0.16  -0.09  -0.08  -0.04  -0.09  -0.13  -0.20  -0.26  -0.34  -0.36  -0.35  -0.30  -0.33  -0.29  -0.18  -0.10   0.01   0.11   0.14   0.10   0.22   0.18   0.38   0.35   0.32   0.27   0.22   0.09  -0.04  -0.13  -0.15  -0.19  -0.12  -0.13  -0.07  -0.16  -0.22  -0.18  -0.11  -0.06   0.06   0.15  -0.02  -0.09  -0.17  -0.22  -0.29  -0.34  -0.33  -0.34  -0.32  -0.27  -0.28  -0.22  -0.25  -0.24  -0.20  -0.19  -0.29  -0.31  -0.36  -0.37  -0.37  -0.35  -0.35  -0.37  -0.34  -0.33  -0.27  -0.25  -0.24  -0.27  -0.29  -0.32  -0.32  -0.31  -0.28  -0.30  -0.32  -0.34  -0.32  -0.33  -0.36  -0.32  -0.29  -0.27  -0.29  -0.29  -0.29  -0.26  -0.23  -0.18  -0.13  -0.08  -0.07  -0.09  -0.04  -0.05  -0.07  -0.08  -0.10  -0.10  -0.17  -0.25  -0.20  -0.21  -0.22  -0.17  -0.15  -0.01   0.00  -0.10  -0.14  -0.11  -0.17  -0.18  -0.17  -0.24  -0.24  -0.24  -0.22  -0.15  -0.17  -0.15  -0.12  -0.05   0.00   0.05   0.09   0.04  -0.02  -0.07  -0.09  -0.12  -0.04  -0.04  -0.11  -0.07  -0.01  -0.06  -0.08  -0.06  -0.08  -0.08  -0.07  -0.06  -0.07  -0.05  -0.09   0.07   0.16   0.14  -0.07  -0.12  -0.06  -0.01  -0.14  -0.18  -0.29  -0.28  -0.26  -0.24  -0.24  -0.25  -0.24  -0.28  -0.28  -0.28  -0.23  -0.27  -0.26  -0.27  -0.22  -0.21  -0.17  -0.14  -0.17  -0.18  -0.16  -0.14  -0.17  -0.16  -0.17  -0.10  -0.10  -0.03   0.05   0.10   0.21   0.22   0.24   0.32   0.32   0.24   0.24   0.18   0.16   0.12   0.12   0.01   0.02  -0.10  -0.16  -0.16  -0.14  -0.12  -0.13  -0.18  -0.17  -0.17  -0.13  -0.10  -0.03  -0.06  -0.05  -0.01  -0.07   0.00   0.06   0.02   0.04  -0.04  -0.02  -0.07  -0.11  -0.00  -0.04   0.02   0.10   0.10   0.14   0.14   0.11   0.12   0.08   0.09   0.04   0.03   0.04   0.06   0.10   0.10   0.13   0.11   0.07   0.08   0.05   0.05   0.03   0.01  -0.02  -0.04  -0.08  -0.18  -0.23  -0.25  -0.22  -0.10  -0.17  -0.15  -0.20  -0.23  -0.24  -0.08  -0.01   0.05   0.02   0.00   0.02   0.03   0.05   0.09   0.13   0.08   0.09   0.15   0.08   0.24   0.25   0.25   0.23   0.22   0.17   0.22   0.22   0.25   0.30   0.33   0.35   0.33   0.34   0.37   0.37   0.31   0.35   0.37   0.38   0.38   0.38   0.38   0.38   0.37   0.39   0.37   0.36   0.35   0.36   0.34   0.33   0.30   0.30   0.25   0.23   0.19   0.20   0.16   0.14   0.15   0.23   0.27   0.32   0.33   0.30   0.33   0.37   0.34   0.32   0.35   0.36   0.37   0.37   0.37   0.37   0.35   0.36   0.36   0.30   0.29   0.30   0.28   0.22   0.23   0.26   0.22   0.24   0.18   0.19   0.14   0.14   0.09   0.07   0.07   0.13   0.18   0.26   0.22   0.16   0.23   0.27   0.15   0.16   0.25   0.21   0.28   0.22   0.25   0.32   0.25   0.22   0.29   0.27   0.23   0.26   0.26   0.22   0.18   0.10   0.04  -0.02   0.05   0.03   0.04   0.02  -0.04  -0.05  -0.04   0.02   0.07  -0.03  -0.09  -0.05  -0.04  -0.16  -0.18  -0.12  -0.17  -0.05  -0.08   0.03   0.06  -0.05  -0.02   0.10   0.07  -0.02   0.06   0.11   0.03  -0.01  -0.11  -0.19  -0.18  -0.15  -0.16  -0.14  -0.13  -0.19  -0.20  -0.22  -0.20  -0.19  -0.24  -0.25  -0.24  -0.27  -0.28  -0.28  -0.28  -0.27  -0.26  -0.26  -0.22  -0.21  -0.25  -0.23  -0.17  -0.19  -0.22  -0.17  -0.13  -0.18  -0.20  -0.21  -0.25  -0.25  -0.23  -0.25  -0.25  -0.23  -0.28  -0.27  -0.29  -0.29  -0.29  -0.31  -0.32  -0.31  -0.32  -0.32  -0.32  -0.31  -0.30  -0.30  -0.30  -0.28  -0.30  -0.31  -0.30  -0.28  -0.29  -0.29  -0.27  -0.26  -0.24  -0.24  -0.05   0.22   0.24   0.22   0.18   0.18   0.24   0.17   0.10   0.08   0.06   0.01  -0.06  -0.08  -0.09  -0.12  -0.10 
  0.76   0.92   1.00   0.88   0.74   0.47   0.42   0.33   0.19   0.21   0.24   0.21   0.17   0.15   0.04  -0.05  -0.14  -0.10  -0.07  -0.09  -0.10  -0.16  -0.11   0.03   0.21   0.34   0.38   0.39   0.37   0.37   0.37   0.37   0.56   0.65   0.73   0.74  -0.20  -0.22  -0.26  -0.18  -0.17  -0.18  -0.19  -0.15  -0.17  -0.19  -0.22  -0.22  -0.20  -0.23  -0.24  -0.22  -0.21  -0.21  -0.27  -0.27  -0.30  -0.30  -0.28  -0.24  -0.24  -0.20  -0.20  -0.18  -0.19  -0.15  -0.01   0.08   0.15   0.18   0.29   0.31   0.35   0.43   0.41   0.43   0.35   0.33   0.19   0.07  -0.01  -0.00  -0.01  -0.04  -0.13  -0.18  -0.25  -0.24  -0.26  -0.26  -0.27  -0.24  -0.20  -0.22  -0.20  -0.17  -0.14  -0.12  -0.09  -0.08  -0.06  -0.02  -0.01   0.00   0.03   0.04   0.08   0.04  -0.01   0.01  -0.08  -0.02   0.00   0.07   0.08   0.10   0.03  -0.08   0.10   0.04   0.06   0.14   0.15   0.18   0.23   0.19   0.09  -0.01   0.00  -0.01   0.01  -0.06  -0.15  -0.07   0.07   0.12   0.14   0.22   0.33   0.32   0.32   0.28   0.25   0.30   0.29   0.22   0.14   0.00  -0.00  -0.03  -0.03  -0.07  -0.01  -0.04  -0.04  -0.03  -0.08  -0.03  -0.03   0.05   0.07   0.11   0.03  -0.00  -0.15  -0.14  -0.10  -0.13  -0.12  -0.15  -0.20  -0.15  -0.07  -0.03   0.03   0.05   0.11   0.08   0.06   0.06   0.04   0.07   0.01  -0.06  -0.15  -0.19  -0.10  -0.10  -0.06  -0.11  -0.14  -0.23  -0.30  -0.39  -0.43  -0.41  -0.35  -0.38  -0.33  -0.22  -0.14  -0.01   0.09   0.14   0.08   0.23   0.21   0.42   0.40   0.36   0.29   0.23   0.09  -0.05  -0.16  -0.18  -0.23  -0.15  -0.16  -0.10  -0.20  -0.25  -0.20  -0.13  -0.06   0.07   0.17  -0.02  -0.11  -0.20  -0.26  -0.34  -0.40  -0.39  -0.41  -0.39  -0.34  -0.35  -0.27  -0.32  -0.31  -0.25  -0.25  -0.34  -0.37  -0.43  -0.44  -0.44  -0.43  -0.42  -0.44  -0.39  -0.38  -0.33  -0.30  -0.29  -0.33  -0.35  -0.38  -0.39  -0.38  -0.34  -0.36  -0.37  -0.38  -0.35  -0.37  -0.41  -0.38  -0.35  -0.32  -0.35  -0.35  -0.35  -0.33  -0.30  -0.23  -0.18  -0.11  -0.09  -0.09  -0.04  -0.05  -0.09  -0.11  -0.13  -0.12  -0.21  -0.29  -0.23  -0.26  -0.26  -0.19  -0.16  -0.01  -0.01  -0.12  -0.17  -0.16  -0.23  -0.24  -0.24  -0.30  -0.30  -0.30  -0.27  -0.21  -0.23  -0.21  -0.19  -0.09  -0.02   0.04   0.08   0.02  -0.05  -0.12  -0.14  -0.17  -0.09  -0.09  -0.14  -0.10  -0.02  -0.07  -0.09  -0.06  -0.08  -0.09  -0.08  -0.07  -0.07  -0.04  -0.10   0.06   0.18   0.12  -0.10  -0.13  -0.09  -0.03  -0.17  -0.21  -0.31  -0.30  -0.28  -0.26  -0.24  -0.25  -0.24  -0.27  -0.26  -0.26  -0.22  -0.24  -0.25  -0.27  -0.23  -0.21  -0.17  -0.14  -0.15  -0.14  -0.13  -0.13  -0.14  -0.13  -0.13  -0.05  -0.06   0.00   0.08   0.13   0.25   0.25   0.26   0.34   0.33   0.26   0.26   0.20   0.18   0.15   0.16   0.04   0.06  -0.06  -0.12  -0.13  -0.13  -0.12  -0.15  -0.19  -0.17  -0.16  -0.10  -0.07   0.00  -0.02  -0.02   0.01  -0.04   0.02   0.06   0.01   0.02  -0.05  -0.04  -0.08  -0.09   0.04  -0.02   0.04   0.12   0.12   0.16   0.16   0.13   0.14   0.11   0.11   0.06   0.05   0.06   0.08   0.12   0.12   0.15   0.13   0.09   0.11   0.08   0.08   0.06   0.04   0.03   0.00  -0.03  -0.13  -0.19  -0.23  -0.20  -0.09  -0.16  -0.14  -0.18  -0.20  -0.21  -0.04  -0.00   0.09   0.06   0.04   0.05   0.06   0.08   0.11   0.16   0.12   0.13   0.16   0.10   0.28   0.29   0.29   0.28   0.26   0.21   0.26   0.26   0.30   0.34   0.37   0.38   0.37   0.38   0.40   0.40   0.35   0.38   0.39   0.40   0.39   0.40   0.41   0.40   0.40   0.42   0.40   0.38   0.39   0.39   0.38   0.36   0.34   0.35   0.31   0.28   0.23   0.25   0.21   0.18   0.19   0.27   0.32   0.37   0.37   0.34   0.37   0.40   0.35   0.33   0.37   0.37   0.39   0.38   0.39   0.39   0.38   0.38   0.38   0.33   0.33   0.34   0.31   0.25   0.26   0.30   0.25   0.27   0.21   0.23   0.18   0.19   0.13   0.11   0.11   0.17   0.22   0.28   0.24   0.18   0.26   0.28   0.14   0.14   0.25   0.19   0.29   0.22   0.25   0.32   0.24   0.21   0.29   0.28   0.23   0.25   0.27   0.23   0.20   0.12   0.06   0.00   0.08   0.06   0.08   0.07  -0.02  -0.03  -0.03   0.03   0.07  -0.03  -0.10  -0.06  -0.07  -0.19  -0.21  -0.17  -0.23  -0.11  -0.14  -0.02   0.02  -0.09  -0.06   0.07   0.05  -0.03   0.04   0.10   0.03  -0.00  -0.10  -0.18  -0.16  -0.15  -0.16  -0.14  -0.13  -0.19  -0.20  -0.23  -0.20  -0.21  -0.27  -0.28  -0.26  -0.31  -0.33  -0.32  -0.32  -0.32  -0.31  -0.32  -0.28  -0.26  -0.30  -0.29  -0.22  -0.23  -0.26  -0.22  -0.17  -0.22  -0.22  -0.24  -0.28  -0.27  -0.25  -0.26  -0.25  -0.22  -0.28  -0.28  -0.31  -0.32  -0.32  -0.35  -0.35  -0.34  -0.36  -0.36  -0.35  -0.36  -0.35  -0.36  -0.35  -0.34  -0.35  -0.36  -0.35  -0.33  -0.33  -0.34  -0.33  -0.32  -0.30  -0.29  -0.08   0.19   0.23   0.23   0.15   0.14   0.22   0.15   0.05   0.03   0.01  -0.05  -0.13  -0.12  -0.12  -0.15  -0.09 
  0.61   0.77   0.88   1.00   0.87   0.59   0.53   0.41   0.26   0.28   0.31   0.27   0.24   0.21   0.08  -0.04  -0.15  -0.12  -0.08  -0.11  -0.12  -0.16  -0.08   0.08   0.29   0.42   0.47   0.47   0.44   0.44   0.45   0.46   0.65   0.66   0.70   0.71  -0.20  -0.24  -0.28  -0.21  -0.20  -0.21  -0.22  -0.17  -0.17  -0.20  -0.24  -0.22  -0.20  -0.23  -0.25  -0.22  -0.21  -0.22  -0.29  -0.29  -0.33  -0.33  -0.30  -0.26  -0.25  -0.20  -0.21  -0.18  -0.20  -0.16   0.01   0.12   0.20   0.24   0.37   0.39   0.44   0.52   0.50   0.52   0.43   0.41   0.25   0.11   0.02   0.04   0.02  -0.03  -0.12  -0.19  -0.27  -0.27  -0.29  -0.29  -0.28  -0.25  -0.22  -0.23  -0.21  -0.18  -0.15  -0.13  -0.10  -0.08  -0.06  -0.02  -0.01   0.01   0.05   0.06   0.11   0.07   0.00   0.04  -0.07   0.01   0.05   0.13   0.14   0.16   0.08  -0.08   0.10   0.07   0.09   0.19   0.22   0.26   0.31   0.25   0.13   0.00  -0.01  -0.01   0.01  -0.06  -0.16  -0.07   0.09   0.15   0.18   0.30   0.41   0.40   0.39   0.34   0.32   0.37   0.35   0.28   0.19   0.04   0.03  -0.00  -0.00  -0.05   0.01  -0.01  -0.02   0.01  -0.05  -0.00  -0.01   0.07   0.10   0.12   0.05   0.02  -0.14  -0.13  -0.08  -0.12  -0.11  -0.15  -0.21  -0.15  -0.06  -0.01   0.07   0.09   0.16   0.13   0.09   0.09   0.07   0.09   0.03  -0.05  -0.16  -0.19  -0.09  -0.08  -0.04  -0.07  -0.12  -0.23  -0.32  -0.43  -0.48  -0.46  -0.40  -0.42  -0.36  -0.24  -0.15  -0.00   0.11   0.17   0.11   0.28   0.27   0.50   0.47   0.42   0.34   0.28   0.10  -0.05  -0.18  -0.20  -0.25  -0.18  -0.20  -0.11  -0.22  -0.28  -0.23  -0.15  -0.07   0.08   0.18  -0.02  -0.12  -0.22  -0.30  -0.39  -0.46  -0.45  -0.46  -0.45  -0.40  -0.40  -0.31  -0.35  -0.34  -0.27  -0.27  -0.38  -0.44  -0.51  -0.51  -0.51  -0.49  -0.48  -0.50  -0.45  -0.43  -0.37  -0.34  -0.32  -0.37  -0.39  -0.44  -0.44  -0.44  -0.39  -0.42  -0.44  -0.45  -0.42  -0.45  -0.48  -0.44  -0.40  -0.37  -0.41  -0.42  -0.41  -0.38  -0.35  -0.28  -0.21  -0.13  -0.10  -0.07  -0.04  -0.04  -0.11  -0.13  -0.15  -0.12  -0.23  -0.32  -0.26  -0.28  -0.29  -0.20  -0.15   0.02   0.02  -0.10  -0.19  -0.19  -0.28  -0.28  -0.28  -0.34  -0.34  -0.34  -0.30  -0.22  -0.27  -0.25  -0.22  -0.12  -0.04   0.03   0.10   0.02  -0.07  -0.14  -0.17  -0.21  -0.13  -0.10  -0.17  -0.13  -0.03  -0.08  -0.11  -0.06  -0.09  -0.10  -0.09  -0.09  -0.08  -0.05  -0.11   0.06   0.19   0.12  -0.13  -0.15  -0.09  -0.01  -0.17  -0.21  -0.33  -0.32  -0.30  -0.28  -0.25  -0.27  -0.26  -0.30  -0.29  -0.28  -0.25  -0.27  -0.28  -0.30  -0.25  -0.25  -0.20  -0.15  -0.15  -0.16  -0.14  -0.14  -0.15  -0.16  -0.12  -0.04  -0.04   0.02   0.10   0.15   0.28   0.28   0.30   0.39   0.38   0.30   0.29   0.25   0.22   0.18   0.18   0.04   0.06  -0.05  -0.14  -0.17  -0.17  -0.17  -0.19  -0.24  -0.21  -0.17  -0.08  -0.04   0.03   0.01   0.01   0.04  -0.02   0.05   0.08   0.01   0.01  -0.08  -0.07  -0.13  -0.14   0.04  -0.03   0.01   0.13   0.15   0.20   0.21   0.18   0.18   0.16   0.15   0.09   0.09   0.11   0.11   0.16   0.17   0.21   0.18   0.14   0.15   0.12   0.11   0.10   0.08   0.06   0.03  -0.00  -0.11  -0.19  -0.25  -0.24  -0.12  -0.20  -0.16  -0.22  -0.23  -0.24  -0.05  -0.03   0.09   0.07   0.05   0.08   0.10   0.12   0.16   0.21   0.17   0.17   0.18   0.10   0.31   0.35   0.34   0.33   0.32   0.25   0.31   0.31   0.35   0.39   0.42   0.44   0.42   0.43   0.45   0.45   0.40   0.43   0.44   0.45   0.45   0.45   0.46   0.46   0.45   0.47   0.46   0.44   0.44   0.45   0.43   0.42   0.39   0.40   0.34   0.33   0.28   0.29   0.26   0.22   0.23   0.31   0.36   0.42   0.41   0.38   0.42   0.45   0.39   0.36   0.41   0.40   0.43   0.43   0.44   0.45   0.43   0.43   0.43   0.39   0.37   0.40   0.36   0.28   0.30   0.34   0.29   0.31   0.24   0.26   0.21   0.22   0.16   0.13   0.13   0.19   0.24   0.31   0.25   0.18   0.28   0.29   0.13   0.12   0.25   0.19   0.33   0.27   0.28   0.35   0.26   0.24   0.32   0.31   0.25   0.28   0.30   0.25   0.22   0.13   0.05  -0.01   0.08   0.06   0.08   0.08  -0.02  -0.04  -0.05   0.01   0.06  -0.07  -0.14  -0.09  -0.12  -0.25  -0.27  -0.22  -0.30  -0.17  -0.20  -0.07  -0.03  -0.14  -0.11   0.04   0.02  -0.08   0.00   0.08   0.01  -0.03  -0.13  -0.23  -0.20  -0.18  -0.19  -0.17  -0.15  -0.22  -0.23  -0.26  -0.24  -0.25  -0.32  -0.33  -0.32  -0.37  -0.39  -0.38  -0.38  -0.38  -0.38  -0.39  -0.35  -0.33  -0.37  -0.35  -0.28  -0.29  -0.32  -0.28  -0.23  -0.28  -0.28  -0.29  -0.34  -0.33  -0.29  -0.31  -0.29  -0.26  -0.32  -0.33  -0.36  -0.37  -0.38  -0.41  -0.41  -0.40  -0.42  -0.42  -0.41  -0.41  -0.41  -0.42  -0.42  -0.40  -0.42  -0.43  -0.42  -0.41  -0.40  -0.40  -0.39  -0.38  -0.36  -0.34  -0.13   0.18   0.24   0.25   0.14   0.12   0.22   0.14   0.03   0.00  -0.02  -0.09  -0.17  -0.15  -0.16  -0.19  -0.10
```

Comment: The data you provided does not match the description you gave, i.e. I see four rows and some many number of columns. Regardless, look at `read.table()` to read your data in, `[` to index the data you want. Then use `sum()` to sum your data. All of this is detailed in the introduction to R manual, which can be found here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html. Also, searching for any of the terms above will yield countless questions on SO which are similar to this one.

Comment: You should still update your question so that the data you describe is represented by the data you show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your pasted data doesn't match your description I'm going to go with the last part of your question... the sum of rows 1-2 and columns 300-400.

```
datf <- read.table('myGreatDataFile')
sum( datf[1:2, 300:400] )
```

You should look in help at all the features of read.table (help(read.table)) and also for indexing data frames, which are the type returned by read.table (help('[')).

But what you really need to do is go through one of the introductory manuals for R.  Judging by your question I suggest that you DO NOT attempt to read any of the R manuals at the main site except "An Introduction to R".  If you get through that and need more help your next best step is go back to the manuals section but go to the contributed documentation linked near the bottom.

(and also read the FAQ about asking questions which was a link to the right of the page when you were editing your question)